# Marketing Mix modeling and synergy terms

Tags: linear-regression, marketing, feature-interaction

I am working on marketing mix models and I would like to know more about the way to include and compute synergy in marketing mix model? I know the existence of one software that uses this kind of model (a log linear model) giving us synergy terms between all marketing variables, but I don't see where it comes from and it does not seem to be just the add of interaction terms (we are talking about model with a lot of explanatory variables..).

I would like to know if you are aware of any marketing research papers on the subject I would appreciate it.

Thank you a lot